# Hashchange or Popstate Issue in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xml, html

Can someone please help me with the following? The hashchange seems to happen, but as soon as I want to go back into some of the following menus the browser gets stuck. I'm currently using Chrome v49.0.2623.112 m. It seems to be working fine on Internet Explorer, but this project will be running off an android device using Chrome.

`**MainMenu**   =   "/VoxeoCXP/DialogMapping/VSN/TelkomKioskService@System?vID=*643434c3c90606f2dffa96317fd0c04907adf2101613e36cbc80909f59df7be2015010fc0561bc7a*"`

`**MenuItem1**  =   "/VoxeoCXP/DialogMapping/VSN/TelkomKioskService@System?vID=*643434c3c90606f26f7ab6112fe0f0f907adf2101613e36cbc80909f59df7be2015010fc0561bc7a*"`

`**MenuItem2**  =   "/VoxeoCXP/DialogMapping/VSN/TelkomKioskService@System?vID=*643434c3c90606f2bf9af6417f20e02907adf2101613e36cbc80909f59df7be2015010fc0561bc7a*"`

`**MenuItem3**  =   "/VoxeoCXP/DialogMapping/VSN/TelkomKioskService@System?vID=*643434c3c90606f20f9aa6510ff0d08907adf2001613e36cbc80909f59df7be2015010fc0561bc7a*"`

I am new to JQuery and had to allow the script and my CSS files to run locally, but even when I run it "remotely" it gives the same issue. Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: "The hashchange seems to happen, but as soon as I want to go back into some of the following menus the browser gets stuck."